# Import XML dictionary in Python

Tags: python, objective-c, xml, parsing, dictionary

I would need some help in python. I'm new in python. I used to program a lot in Objective-C.

### In Objective-C I was able to save a NSDictionary as a xml file and load it directly with a simple command. Here is an example of a xml dictionary I saved:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>1</key>
    <string>Object One</string>
    <key>2</key>
    <string>Object Two</string>
    <key>3</key>
    <string>Object Three</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

If I load it in Objective-C , I can directly get the dictionary as a NSDictionary.

So my question is: how can I do that easily in Python. I found some stuff using parsers such as lxml. I managed to load the data but I was not able to get a dictionary with only the keys and the values. 
I searched lot on the internet but wasn't able to find something suitable. 
Does anyone has an idea or an advice?

I tried this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410469-xml-as-dictionary/
but I didn't manage to make it work.

In advance, Thank you very much!

Comment: "I didn't manage to make it work." Well, what was wrong with it?

Comment: I got this error:     if len(element) == 1 or element[0].tag != element[1].tag:
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1054, in lxml.etree._Element.__getitem__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:38293)
IndexError: list index out of range

I know that it means that I am going to far some where but I didn't change the code except that when I run it it said that I need to change "if element" into "if element is not None"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use plistlib: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/plistlib.html

```
pl = readPlist(pathOrFile)
print(pl["1"])
```

Comment: @user1314776 stackoverflow has a built in mechanism for indicating this: Just mark the answer as "accepted". (If somebody has a better answer, you can always change this later)